# Как вывести одно слово в виде ссылки?

Tags: php, html

Добрый день всем! Подскажите пожалуйста, есть строка вида: "слово 1, слово 2"

Есть php код:

```html
<?
$str = "слово1,слово2";
for($i=0;$i<count($p);$i++) {
    echo '<a href="#">'.$p[$i].'</a>'; 
}
?>
```

Сейчас в результате выводится слово1слово2

слово1слово2

Как сделать подстановку в ссылку значения, так чтобы для каждой новой ссылки выводилось новое слово?

```html
<a href="">слово1</a>

<a href="">слово2</a>
```

Весь код страницы:

```html
<?

preg_match('/\{[,0-9]{1,120}\}/', $current_sub['AnimFotoId'],$gal,PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$gal = $gal[0][0];
$gal = preg_replace('/\{/', '',$gal);
$gal = explode(',',preg_replace('/\}/', '',$gal));
if (!count($gal)) {
unset($gal);
}
?>

<?
$str = $current_sub['AnimTitleFoto'];
$strArray = explode(",", $str);

$mp = '';                 

?>


                        <?
                        if ($gal[0] <> '') {?>
                        
                        <div class="fotos" style="padding:30px;padding-top:0px;text-align:center">
                        <?
                        
                        echo '<div class="g-content"><h2>'.$current_sub["AnimFotoZagolovok"].'</h2></div> ';
                        echo '<div class="block-events">';
                        echo '<div class="items">';
                        
                        
                       foreach ($gal as $item) {
                        $item = trim($item);
                        $format = '.jpg';
                 
                        if (!@fopen('http://k-chydes.ru/netcat_files/2344_'.$item.$format,'r')) {
                        $format = '.JPG';
                        }
                        
                        
                       echo '<div class="item">';
                        echo '<div class="image"><span><a style="margin:10px;" href="/main/portfolio/portfolio_'.$item.'.html"><img  width="256" height="170" src="/netcat_files/2344_'.$item.$format.'" /></a></span></div>';
  echo '<div class="title">';
  
echo '<a href="#">';

$i = 0;

    foreach ($strArray as $key => $word) {

          if($i == $key)
                {
          $mp .= ''.$strArray[$key].''; 
                    }
    }

echo $mp;

$i++;

echo '</a>';       
  
  echo '</div>';
                       
                        echo '</div>';
                        }
                        echo '</div>';
                        echo '</div>';
                         ?>
                        </div>
                        <?
                        
                        }
                        ?>
```

Comment: `$p = explode("," $str);`

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь функцией `explode`
http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php

```
<?php
    $str = "слово1,слово2";
    $strArray = explode(",", $str);

    foreach ($strArray as $key => $word) {
        echo '<a href="#">'.$word.'</a>'; 
    }
```

**Офтопик** не издевайтесь над собой, форматируйте код так , что бы было понятно что и где.

Ваш код после правки:

```
<?php

preg_match('/\{[,0-9]{1,120}\}/', $current_sub['AnimFotoId'], $gal, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$gal = $gal[0][0];
$gal = preg_replace('/\{/', '',$gal);
$gal = explode(',',preg_replace('/\}/', '',$gal));
if (!count($gal)) {
    unset($gal);
}

$strArray = explode(",", $current_sub['AnimTitleFoto']);
if ($gal[0] <> '') {?>
    <div class="fotos" style="padding:30px;padding-top:0px;text-align:center">
    <?
        echo '<div class="g-content"><h2>'.$current_sub["AnimFotoZagolovok"].'</h2></div> ';
        echo '<div class="block-events">';
            echo '<div class="items">';
                foreach ($gal as $key => $item) {
                    $item = trim($item);
                    $format = '.jpg';
                    if (!@fopen('http://k-chydes.ru/netcat_files/2344_'.$item.$format,'r')) {
                        $format = '.JPG';
                    }

                    echo '<div class="item">';
                        echo '<div class="image"><span><a style="margin:10px;" href="/main/portfolio/portfolio_'.$item.'.html"><img  width="256" height="170" src="/netcat_files/2344_'.$item.$format.'" /></a></span></div>';
                        echo '<div class="title">';
                            // Если количество и порядок картинок и подписей совпадает(по идее должно) то можно не мудрить.
                            // Ключ ($key) будет совпадать
                            if (isset($strArray[$key])) {
                                echo '<a href="#">';
                                    echo $strArray[$key];
                                echo '</a>';
                            }
                        echo '</div>';
                    echo '</div>';
                }

            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>'; ?>
    </div>
<? } ?>
```

На правах codereview:

1. `@` - в коде быть не должно. Ошибки надо обрабатывать, а не прятать
2. `fopen('http://k-chydes.ru/netcat_files/2344...` - Запрос к чужому ресурсу в цикле. Плохая идея, так как долго, плюс где гарантия что ресурс доступен?
3. Пользуйтесь шаблонизаторами (например twig https://twig.sensiolabs.org/). Что бы не мешать так html и php.
4. Не знаю где и как вы получаете "$current_sub" но обработка быглядит мутно.

Comment: я воспользовался функцией explode, но у меня выводится по прежнему <a href="">слово1слово2</a>

Comment: @Demon Вы пробовали код из моего ответа?(сомневаюсь) Покажите код который неправильно исполняеться!

Comment: Да это работает, а как сделать чтобы эти две ссылки выводились не рядом в одну строку а под 2 разными изображениями?

Comment: @demon  А как изображения выводятся? Код покажите.

Comment: echo '<div class="item">';
   echo '<div class="image"><span><a style="margin:10px;" href="/main/portfolio/portfolio_1.html"><img  width="256" height="170" src="/netcat_files/2344_'.$item.$format.'" /></a></span></div>';echo '</div>';

Comment: @Demon Скопируйте полностью этот код в ваш вопрос. Так непонятно.

Comment: Я скопировал весь код страницы в вопрос, посмотрите мне нужно сделать чтобы под картинками выводились разные ссылки. $current_sub['AnimTitleFoto'] это массив который содержит слово1, слово2

Comment: @Demon Ваш код в ответе.